# How to get window handle by PID in autohotkey?

Tags: autohotkey

I want to get window handle by PID in autohotkey, because title of the window is always changing. If any one wonder, I want to get handle of last.fm main window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11957430/how-to-get-window-handle-by-pid-in-autohotkey